# Pull Data with hyperlinks in excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, editor, data-analysis, data-extraction

I am trying to pull data from website along with hyperlinks but I am just able to get the texts and not the hyperlinks (with text). Is there any way we could pull the table from web in its original format (with hyperlinks). Thank you

Comment: Do you have any attempts? You need to add in any code you've attempted to your question as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s. And there is no direct relation between Excel and web pages. Please update your question. Then it will be more likely to receive a relevant answer.

Comment: In excel, there is a tool( in Data tab > Get Data > From Web ) to import the tables from online web pages. The tables is imported with text but not the hyperlinks. I want to import the text with hyperlinks from that table. There is no such code so cannot paste it. but here is the short video of what I am talking about https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yTAyVXzFGg